# tensor product of $C^*$-algebras.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In most reference books about tensor product of $C^*$-algebras, the authors only give the definition of the spatial , maximal tensor product of unital $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$.

When $A$ and $B$ are non-unital, how to define the minimal tensor product and maximal tensor product?
For example, in the non-unital case, can we define the maxiaml $C^*$ norm of $A\odot B$ as following?

$\|x\|_{max}=\sup_{\pi}\|\pi(x)\|$, where $\pi:A\odot B \to B(H)$ is a representation of $A\odot B$.

Comment: See Brown and Ozawa. The spatial and maximal tensor products are defined in exactly the same way.

Comment: In the definition,the authors let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras.It means that the $C^*$-algebras can be non-uintal?

Comment: Sure, there is nothing in these definitions that depends on a unit.